# Passing the template variable to the Observers from the Subject - Observe design pattern

Tags: c++, templates, design-patterns

I am utilizing an observer design pattern for this simple use case whereupon a change in a `Subject` concrete class, the template value `_x` is passed to the observers via `notify()` however that will require `Subject` to be a template class which I don't want.

Instead of making `Subject` a template class, I made `notify` a template function and made `Observer` a template to allow the passing of a template `value` in `update()` but that will cause problems inside `Subject` which doesn't need to be a template class.

Any ideas on getting around this problem without making `Subject` template?

```
class Subject;

template<typename T>
class Observer
{
    public:
    virtual void update(T value, Subject *) = 0;
};

class Subject
{
    std::vector<Observer<T>*> _obs;

    public:
    void attach(Observer<T>* obs)
    {
        _obs.push_back(obs);
    }

    template<typename T>
    void notify(T value)
    {
        for (auto& o: _obs)
        {
            o->update(value, this);
        }
    }
};

template<typename T>
class B : public Observer<T>
{
    public:
    void update(T value, Subject* sub)
    {
        std::cout << "Value set = " << value << std::endl;
    }
};

template<typename T>
class A : public Subject
{
    T _x;
    public:
    void set(T value)
    {
        _x = value;
        notify(_x); // want to pass T without making Subject template
    }
};

int main() 
{
    A<int> a1;
    B <int> b1;

    a1.attach(&b1);
    a1.set(10);
}
```

Comment: You have a hidden dependency - `notify` does not work for all `T`, but only for those `T` compatible with all the attached observers. Suppose that the current code would compile, what do you expect to happen for `subject.notify(12)` for an attached `Observer<std::string>`? Surely there must be a compilation error and hence `T` must be known at compile time and cannot be erased.

Comment: actually I meant to have `T` instead of `int` in `A::set()`. And observer is a template of the same `T` which it should be able to deduce

Comment: `A` does not matter here, the problem is with `Subject` itself, what you want is impossible you cannot both erase `T` and check `o->update(value, this);` for correctness. Please specify what should happen in `notify` when you pass incorrect type given some attached observers.

Comment: I mentioned there won't be any difference in types b/w observer and subject. `subject` notifying an `int` 12 would mean `observer`'s template type would be `int` as well. Sorry if I'm not understanding you well.

Comment: But the code does not enforce that and it cannot enforce that without knowing `observer`'s template type, hence my repeated statements that the type cannot be erased from `Subject`. You cannot just store `std::vector<Observer*> _obs;` somehow without `T` because `o->update(value, this);` cannot be called even if you know the type of `value`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you really promise that for `notify<T>`, there are only `Observer<T>`, then you could use a dynamic_cast safely:

```
class Subject;
class ObsBase{
    virtual ~ObsBase()=default;
};
template<typename T>
class Observer:public ObsBase
{
    public:
    virtual void update(T value, Subject *) = 0;
};

class Subject
{
    //If this is the owner, use std::unique_ptr<ObsBase>
    std::vector<ObsBase*> _obs;

    public:
    void attach(ObsBase* obs)
    {
        _obs.push_back(obs);
    }

    template<typename T>
    void notify(T value)
    {
        for (ObsBase* o: _obs)
        {
            auto* d = dynamic_cast<Observer<T>*>(o);
            if(d!=nullptr)
                d->update(value, this);
        }
    }
};
```

Comment: interesting. 1) is there a way to enforce the same types between `Observer`, concrete `Subject` class `A`, and `Subject::notify()`? 2) is `dynamic_cast` really required given each `Observer` object shall have `update()` implemented since it's a pure virtual anyway? Also you probably meant to have a public `ObsBase` destructor no?

Comment: nvm 2). Just realized you're downcasting `ObsBase` to `Observer` via `dynamic_cast`

Comment: Yes, the destructor should have been public.  1) Yes, make `Subject` a template of `T`. Otherwise of course not, that is what I was talking about, either you erase the type as I did and "promise" the observers are the same or you don't. 2) `update` cannot be pushed to `ObsBase` without making it a template class which defeats its purpose. Is there are a particular reason for not simply making `Subject<T>`?

Comment: it's just I have another class that stores a list of `Subject*` and if it's a template, I don't see how that would work

Comment: Yea, that unfortunately happens often to me too, templates tend to spread. What worked for me was to really take some time and think out the design, especially what I really need at compile-time and what should be covered by interfaces.